# Cant recieve verification code Telegram API (Telethon)

Tags: python, telegram, telethon, telegram-api

I have next code:

```
from telethon import TelegramClient, events, sync
from telethon.tl.functions.users import GetFullUserRequest
from telethon.tl.functions.messages import CheckChatInviteRequest
from telethon.tl.functions.channels import GetFullChannelRequest
import time
import asyncio
import socks
import random

import requests
import json
import os

api_id = 'MY API ID HERE'
api_hash = 'MY ID HASH HERE'

names = []
surnames = []

f = open('surnames.txt')
for line in f:
    surnames.append(line)
f.close()

f = open('names.txt')
for line in f:
    names.append(line)
f.close()

first_name = random.choice(names)[:-1]
last_name = random.choice(surnames)[:-1]

print(f"{first_name} {last_name}")


phone_number = '+916387698598'
client = TelegramClient(phone_number, api_id, api_hash)
client.connect()

#code_request = client.send_code_request(phone_number, force_sms=True)
#if i use force_sms=True it returns error telethon.errors.rpcerrorlist.SendCodeUnavailableError:  (caused by ResendCodeRequest)
code_request = client.send_code_request(phone_number) #when i use it without forcing SMS it send code to telegram
#code stuck here because it is unused nuber and it is obviously that i cant get code in telegram app that is why i need sms
client.sign_up(input('Enter code: '), first_name=first_name, last_name=last_name, phone=phone_number, phone_code_hash=code_request)
client.start()
```

`client.send_code_request()` return this object `SentCode(type=SentCodeTypeApp(length=5), phone_code_hash='7b858e791fadefae8b', next_type=None, timeout=None)` to `code_request`. This object telethon get from Telegram API directly.
As i understand from this object Telegram dont have any timeout to changeSentCodeTypeApp to SentCodeTypeSMS. Also next_type field is empty too.

When i try to force_sms=True Telethon send to api auth.resendCode function, api returns SEND_CODE_UNAVAILABLE error.
[auth.resendCode structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CUzDu.png)

Structure of SentCode object due to docs: [Structure of SentCode object due to docs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iS5iE.png)

I tried to work from Telethon source code and Telegram give same requests to Telethon. So there no problems with Telethon, this is telegram issue. Alse i tried to set custom device_model:
`client = TelegramClient(f"{number}", api_id, api_hash, proxy=proxy, device_model="Xiaomi Mi 11 Lite", system_version="12(31)", app_version="Telegram Android 9.4.6")`
it doesnt help too.
Also i tried to set custom auth code settings (by default it use default device settings) in send_code_request() metgod in Telethon source code but it doesnt help.
Maybe you know how to force telegram to send code via sms?? I spent 2 days trying solve this problem :(

Comment: You are likely affected by https://github.com/LonamiWebs/Telethon/issues/4050.